# Разрыв страницы как в pdf файла

Tags: html, css

Нужно сверстать HTML-страницу, чтобы она была разделена на страницы, как в PDF файлах(по блокам, чтоб при её печатим было формата А4, например),между страницами делать небольшой разрыв и каждая страница начиналась с определённого участка кода. Как это организовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рассмотрите возможность использования CSS свойств `page-break-after`, `page-break-before`, `page-break-inside`.